# send hex value to the server using ethernet in c

Tags: c, server, ethernet, tcpserver

I want to send 792 byte data from my gateway to the server using ethernet. I take all 792 data to the inside `gateway.tcp_message` which size is `1024`. Before sending this datas to server, I put all data inside data buffer, to do that I use `memcpy` function. and then send to server. But When I check the server,  only first 5 byte data is coming every time and rest 787 data are missing.

The problem was about `data[6] = 0` . So, when trying to send data and it encounters to `6` and byte which is `0`, it just stop sending. That is why other data are missing. How to avoid this problem? Because `0` value should be inside the data buffer.

```
Gateway.tcp_message_length=1024;
u8_t   data[1024];
memcpy(data,Gateway.tcp_message,Gateway.tcp_message_length);
```

What do you advice to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Check on the server the number of bytes received.

Comment: I checked the number of bytes received. it is 779.  it doesnt receive the data after 779. byte. when ı check the buffer, value of 779. byte is zero. when program see zero value, it stop sending. I guess program understand that is null, but I dont know why